# implicit promotion to avoid overflow in std::partial_sum

Tags: c++, stl, overflow

This code suffers from overflow because the type of intermediate results does not depend on the destination type:

```
vector< uint8_t > increments;
…
vector< uint32_t > increasing( increments.size() );
partial_sum( increments.begin(), increments.end(), increasing.begin() );
```

However, so does this (GCC 4.2):

```
partial_sum( increments.begin(), increments.end(), increasing.begin(),
             plus< uint32_t >() );
```

Shouldn't `plus< uint32_t >` promote its operands and avoid the overflow?

**Edit:** I'm too SO-addicted. After a short break, I sat back down and checked the implementation. It does this:

```
  /* input_iterator::value_type */ __value = __binary_op(__value, *__first);
  *++__result = __value;
```

I don't think that's compliant, so I'll check the latest version and maybe file a bug… and here we go: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42943

Comment: I think you're right - the problem isn't whether `plus` converts its parameters (it does, of course), the problem is that 26.4.3/1 says that the value assigned to the second output is `binary_op(*first, *(first+1))`, not `InputIterator::value_type(binary_op(*first, *(first+1))`. But how should it be implemented? If BinaryOperation has a `result_type` then it could be using that, but functions don't have a result_type, and surely you can pass a function pointer to partial_sum? Maybe it's too late at night for me...

Comment: Ahh, function pointers. I can't find any specific requirements of the operation object, except §25/8 (sorta), which is only that it can be called with two arguments. Templates can extract the return type from a function, although that makes the change more high-impact.

Comment: Rather than deducing the type from the BinaryFunction, why not use the value_type of the OutputIterator instead of the type of the InputIterator?

Comment: @visitor: I assume because for instance the OutputIterator might have a very narrow value type, in which case you also don't want the information to be discarded prior to the actual assignment. It makes no difference when the BinaryFunction is modulo addition, since doing the conversion early doesn't alter the result, but for other functions it would. But worse, the OutputIterator's value type might not even be convertible to the parameter type of binary_op. The standard doesn't say it has to be, so implementations can't assume it.

Comment: I mean, to avoid overflow, you'd rather go from a smaller to a larger type, rather than try to store the results in an even smaller type. And eventually, if the types are different then either there are conversions or you get a compiler error one way or another. And why couldn't you give it a binary_op that can accept the output type?

Comment: @visitor: You don't want to do much with the OutputIterator's value_type because output iterators generally have loose requirements and it might be a weird private class only allowing assignment. Also, the way the standard was originally written showed a chain of "nested" function calls, suggesting that intermediate values be implicit casted directly from result_type to argument_1_type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#539, `partial_sum` has been completely redefined since n3000 (the latest release):

> Effects: Let VT be InputIterator's
>   value type. For a nonempty range,
>   initializes an accumulator acc of type
>   VT with *first  and performs *result =
>   acc. For every iterator i in [first +
>   1, last) in order, acc is then
>   modified by acc = acc + *i or acc =
>   binary_op(acc, *i)  and is assigned to
>   *(result + (i - first)).

and

> The 'widening' behaviour can then be
>   obtained by writing a custom proxy
>   iterator, which is somewhat involved.

I really can't see the advantage of doing things this way. Reading the defect report, I don't see any justification besides

> The intent of the algorithms is to perform their calculations using the
>   type of the input iterator.

Arrrgh.

**Edit:** I went ahead and implemented a widening input iterator. Works as advertised.

```
template< class Base, class Wider >
struct widen_iter : iterator< input_iterator_tag, Wider > {
    Base b;
    widen_iter( Base const &inb = Base() ) : b( inb ) {}
    Wider operator*() const { return Wider( *b ); }
    Wider const *operator->() const { Wider t( *b ), *ta = &t; return ta; }
    widen_iter &operator++() { ++ b; return *this; }
    widen_iter operator++(int) { widen_iter t = *this; ++ b; return t; }
    bool operator==( widen_iter const &r ) const { return b == r.b; }
    bool operator!=( widen_iter const &r ) const { return b != r.b; }
};
template< class Wider, class Base >
widen_iter< Base, Wider >
widener( Base b ) { return widen_iter< Base, Wider >( b ); }
```

Would be a lot shorter if there were a generic filter-by-functor input iterator.

Comment: Use std::accumulate instead, with the `init` value storing and incrementing the output iterator and using the wider type to store the running total? accumulate guarantees that the additions are performed in order.

Comment: +1 Can't see why avoiding overflow should be made harder than achieving overflow. As a solution: write your own partial_sum?

Comment: @Steve: That might be a shorter solution. `init` only has to implement `operator+` and `operator=`. Very specific, though. @Uncle: Yeah, looks like that would also be a more practical solution, although doing it properly (accepting fn ptrs) would require template introspection.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: you could write your own `partial_sum_convert` that's identical to the standard one except with an additional template parameter `AccumulatorType`. Make it the first parameter, so that you don't have to specify the iterator types when you call it. Then no introspection needed, just call `partial_sum_convert<uint32_t>(first, last, out, op);`. If the return type of op isn't assignable to AccumulatorType, or the op can't take (AccumulatorType, InputIterator::value_type) as parameters, that's the caller's problem.

Comment: ... still quite specific, but then it's being done to address a specific difficulty with using partial_sum. If there are other uses for your widening iterator, then that's probably a better solution overall.

Comment: @Steve: agreed. There are certainly other uses for a generic filtering input iterator, though. Then all you need is `template< class D, class S > D conv( S const &s ) { return D(s); }` and `partial_sum( filterer< conv >( first ), filterer< conv >( last ), result )`, assuming `filterer` is a properly intelligent factory. I don't have Boost installed but it looks like `boost::transform_iterator` implements `filter`.